# how to convert a column of strings consisting of integers(pixels) separated by space into a dataframe with approx 28000 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with approx 28000 rows and just one column "pixels".Each cell has 2304 integers separated by a single space.I have to convert it into a dataframe with 2304 fields i.e I want to convert each string consisting of space separated 2304 integers into rows of a dataframe with 2304 columns
[image: This is the screenshot of first 5 rows of original dataframe 'X_train']

For example-In the above image,in 1st row,70,80,82,72... are in same column separated by space,I want them to be in different columns.For this,i wrote the below code.But on running the code,I am not getting the output(very slow execution),may be due to large amount of data.How can I solve this problem?

```
k =0
rows_list = []
for row in X_train.itertuples():
    s = X_train.at[k,"pixels"].split(' ')
    image_data = np.asarray(s)
    rows_list.append(image_data)
    k+=1
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df.head()
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.split`

```
yourdf=df.plxels.str.split(' ',expand=True)
```